# Executing Ansible playbook in Jenkins to provision EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am trying to run a Ansible playbook that provisions EC2 instances in AWS using Jenkins.
My Jenkins application is installed on an EC2 that has required roles to provision instances, and my JENKINS_USER is ec2-user.
I am able to execute the playbook manually when logged in as ec2-user. However, when I try to execute the same exact Ansible command, Jenkins stalls indefinitely.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Provision-AWS-Environment-dev
[Provision-AWS-Environment-dev] $ /bin/ansible-playbook /home/ec2-user/efx-devops-jenkins/aws/awsprovision.yml -i /home/ec2-user/efx-devops-jenkins/aws/inventories/dev/hosts -s -f 5 -vvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAYBOOK: awsprovision.yml *****************************************************
[0;34m2 plays in /home/ec2-user/efx-devops-jenkins/aws/awsprovision.yml[0m

PLAY [awsmaster] ***************************************************************

TASK [provision : Provison "3" ec2 instances in "ap-southeast-2"] **************
[1;30mtask path: /home/ec2-user/efx-devops-jenkins/aws/roles/provision/tasks/main.yml:5[0m
[0;34mUsing module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/amazon/ec2.py[0m
[0;34m<10.39.144.187> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user[0m
[0;34m<10.39.144.187> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615 `" ) && sleep 0'[0m
[0;34m<10.39.144.187> PUT /tmp/tmpvvKnfU TO /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615/ec2.py[0m
[0;34m<10.39.144.187> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615/ /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615/ec2.py && sleep 0'[0m
[0;34m<10.39.144.187> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-uatxqcnoparsvzhjhxvlccmbjwaxjqaz; /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615/ec2.py; rm -rf "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1489656061.65-268771004227615/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0'[0m
```

Can anyone identify why I am not able to execute the playbook using Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Jenkins Master node (where the Ansible playbook was being executed), was missing some Environmental Variables (Configured under Manage Jenkins>Manage Node> Configure Master). See below list of variable I added to Jenkins Master node.

```
Name: http_proxy
Value: http://proxy.com:123

Name: PATH
Value: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

Name: SUDO_COMMAND
Value: /bin/su ec2-user

Name: SUDO_USER
Value: svc_ansible_lab
```

Once I added the above variables, I was able to execute the Ansible Playbooks with no issues.